# What does “soft/hard nproc” mean on Linux

Tags: limits

What does "hard/soft nproc"mean on CentOS7
What diffrent with  'hard/soft nproc' or 'hard/soft noproc'
THS

/etc/security/limits.conf
*  hard nofile   131702
*  soft nofile   131702
*  hard nproc   131702
*  soft nproc   131702
*  hard core   unlimited
*  soft core   unlimited
*  hard memlock   unlimited
*  soft memlock   unlimited

Answer (score 0):

```
nofile               # The total number of files that can be opened  
npro                 # The total number of threads that can be opened  
core unlimited       # not limited  
memlock unlimted     # not limited
```